# Does the size of my Arch always grow when I install updates?

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, rolling-release

Since Arch Linux is a rolling distributive, each time I update a system by "pacman -Syu" it downloads updates of about 50-100Mb and then it unzips them which make them even bigger.

I wonder, does that mean that it takes more and more my disk space and the total size of my Arch **always** grows? It never gets smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point here is that pacman keep populating your /var/cache. Which means that **if you don't do the cleaning yourself**, it will indefinitely grow!
Apart from that, you can imagine that some software will take more space, some may take less.

If you do your ***housekeeping*** well, it shouldn't increase that much. 
With Arch, you are in charge and can really optimize everything. No software are added for no reason, update/upgrade happens only when you decide, and you can exclude whatever you want from being updated.

Comment: apart from /var/cache, doesn't installing new software imply that it takes space always? that is, however often I clean /var/cache, I'll still have less and less space each time I install an update.

Comment: Of course, if you install new software, you'll take up some space. That's fair, isn't it? ;) I guess most software will also tend to grow, as they bring new features and so on ; some may get optimised and lose weight, but I doubt it is the common trend. All this is quite system independent. Using arch you're on the bleeding edge side of the world, and one that's very optimised too.

Comment: how often is it recommended to run "sudo pacman -Suy"?

Comment: I must say I tend to upgrade nearly everytime I notice there is something to upgrade :) And I just noticed that sometimes your Net Upgrade size is negative, meaning it can go down in size.

Answer (score 4):

The … situation :) … here is that `pacman` doesn't clean its package cache. This is by design. Quoting [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman#Cleaning_the_package_cache):

> pacman stores its downloaded packages in `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/` and
>   does not remove the old or uninstalled versions automatically,
>   therefore it is necessary to deliberately clean up that folder
>   periodically to prevent such folder to grow indefinitely in size.
>
> The built-in option to remove all the cached packages that are not
>   currently installed is:
>
> ```
> # pacman -Sc
> ```

However, **running this blindly is not advisable**. Do read the Arch Wiki before doing this; there are better ways around this problem.

Comment: does that answer my question?

Comment: @OskarK. Doesn't it? Did you see that part of the quote where it says "grow indefinitely in size"?

Comment: Also you can use `paccache`, read: [Cleaning the package cache](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Cleaning_the_package_cache)